# IE 9 Script error SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a jQuery popup window that works in Firefox.

However, I am getting the following error message on line 1 of my html page:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' 
popup_1.html, line 1 character 1

The only code I have in line 1 is:

```
<html>
```

When I run the IE9 debugger, I am getting an error on something called

```
script block(1)
```

But I am not using any javascript named "script block" is this an Internet Explorer add on or something?

Answer (score 13):

Looks like I had to add the html 5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I got this error in IE10.  The issue was the browser was running in compatibillity mode.  Hit F12 and turn it off.  The error is gone.

[image]

Comment: I also set Document Mode to Standards

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following tag solved this issue for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

This error usually happens because IE creates JS variables for every HTML node and it conflicts with jQuery & other JS things you're adding.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following tags:

1. `<!DOCTYPE html>` (and, of course, close this tag too)
2. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Both these tags tell IE to render the page using Edge, the latest renderer.